# Maven : Skip all plugins except the compile

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-plugin

I want to compile a list of projects in a directory using a python script. {The question is not related with Python.Its used for some data processing purpose and compiling the list of project is a step within the chain of activities performed. }
I am calling system("mvn compile") on each of the project.While doing so, I notice the project has so many plugins like javadoc, checkstyle, etc., which i do not want to execute.
I would like to simply compile all the projects and does not want to call other plugins(even from parent pom.xml).

I do not want to edit pom.xml for each project and introduce dev profile, because its going to take lot of time and the project list is not constant.

I need the CLI command to achieve this, similar to -Dmaven.test.skip=True. The command should disable all plugins and only run compile goal.(even i am using mvn compile, but in some cases, the reactor projects or parent pom have other plugins which are being run)

I tried various forums and does not find a way to do this yet.
Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use a python script ? For what purpose ? Can you show the directory structure ?

Comment: I think if you really wanted to do this you would need to look at what plugins you want to skip, and probably only run the compile goal. Most support some flavor of skip param(for example, as you noted, you can skip tests via -Dmaven.test.skip or -DskipTests, and skip javadoc via -Dmaven.javadoc.skip, etc). That being said, I'd really advise you to take a pass at re-working your poms, or maybe introducing a parent pom to introduce a new profile or something like that. May I ask why you want to skip all of these plugins?

Comment: @khmarbaise - The python scripts does some other tasks also and iterates the directory and call mvn compile in the sub folders. The folder structure would be like Main folder > project folder{s}.

Comment: @NickDeFazio thanks for your comment. I am aware of such -Dmaven.javadoc.skip. but in this setup , there will be lot of projects which are very dynamic will be fed as input to the script and its really isn't practical to find all those plugins and add disable comments during run time dynamically. The program is interested in source code files only and does not want to follow other steps like Javadoc as you correctly understood.

Comment: Why do you use python ? I don't understand the need for python? what kind of problem are you trying to solve with Python?

Comment: @khmarbaise As i stated above, python is used for some other (data extraction )tasks.

Comment: Sorry this is a circle..you didn't really answer the question: What is the problem you are trying to solve with Pythin in a Java build? Data extraction ? for a build? Can you be more specific...

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry I really do not know how to make you understand. I have updated my question. please check

Comment: Ok..I'm not sure if you are aware of multi module builds furthermore of CI solutions which can handle things like this...apart from this if you run `mvn compile`  the life cycle runs and runs the appropriate plugins which is intended to do...What I don't understand is why you don't want to run plugins? You can of course skip parts of them but that sounds you haven't configured you maven build very good...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your suggestions. multi module will not work as every folder is having different projects. secondly the projects are open source so, not having control of plugins and not configured by myself.

Comment: If those projects are open source so higly likely they are available via Maven Central?

Comment: @khmarbaise there are some outdated plugins too. i just need compiled code rather than executing some plugin( like maven-license-plugin for instance), which is enforced by some project and also cause the build to fail if the configurations are not correct.

Comment: As I said before consume them from Central...I don't see the need for what you are doing...Can more specific what the reasons are you doing that way? What problem you have?